# n-tier architecture approach asp.net web application clearing confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net

Well i want to know how many architecture approaches we can use in asp.net web application. i was asked about it. i told him that i use a appcode for dal and bal and the presentation layer. but he was not convince. basically i want to ask what web application architecture an asp.net web application guru would use keeping in mind the different metrics ( i am talking minus web services or any SOA thing)

Comment: Architecture of any application depend upon the nature and the size of the application. So first you tell which type of application you want to build

Comment: i am taklking about the enterprise level application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Classic 2 tiers app

Is the one you described: You have the client (the browser) connecting to the server (can be configured as several servers) running an ASP app with your AppCode classes acceding the database in the local network (or same machine)

### n-tiers app

You can use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to delived n-tiers app where the client connect to the server and the server connect to WCF services running on the same server or in several other servers

*Note: This is the short story and the naming is subject to debate.*